# Windows Event Forwarding (WEF) .xml query

Tags: xml, windows

I'm using a series of xml queries to create a WEF subscription using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection as a rough guide. I have a regulatory requirement to capture and audit event ID 4688 process creation. This is a high volume event under normal circumstances and in my environment this is compounded by the fact that we are forced to use Tanium as our EDR solution and Tanium winds up being responsible for half of all process creation events on our systems. So ... I would like to build my xml query to capture the 4688 events but exclude those where the NewProcessName or ParentProcessName includes *Tanium*

The basic query, without the exclusion for Tanium looks like this:

```
<Query Id="18" Path="Security">
<!-- Process Create (4688) -->
<Select Path="Security">*[System[EventID=4688]]</Select>
</Query>
```

Any help figuring out how to filter out the Tanium related events would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is long and tortured, by try this xpath expression:

```
*[System[EventID=4688]][not(//Data[(@Name="NewProcessName" and (contains(./text(),'Tanium'))) or
(@Name="ParentProcessName" and (contains(./text(),'Tanium')))])]
```

Comment: Jack - thanks for the response. Unfortunately I have discovered that Windows only supports a limited version of Xpath filtering for Windows Event Forwarding. The "contains" function is not supported.

Comment: @MattZ - Sorry to hear that - I wasn't aware of how limited xpath support is in WEF. Xpath is on ver 3.1 and WEF can't even include full ver 1.0 support... I'm fresh out of ideas; maybe pipe the output into a file and then load it into an application that supports full xpath search?